# Does an infrared beam get refracted while travelling through a medium?

Tags: optics

Assuming that the medium does not absorb infrared light of that wavelength, is it possible to observe refraction of the beam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fairly standard laboratory demonstration where the set up is a high power filament light bulb (500 W), a couple of slits to collimate the light which then passes through a grass prism.

The white light is refracted and dispersed by the prism and a white spectrum is seen on a screen.

A thermometer with a blackened thermometer bulb placed beyond the red part of the spectrum indicates a temperature which greater than one placed in the yellow part of the spectrum which indicates the presence of radiation beyond the red part of the spectrum - infra red.

[image]

Replacing the glass prism with a rock salt prism produces a larger  temperature rise on the thermometer because rock salt is transparent (does not absorb) to infrared radiation.

In [this link from the Royal Society](http://invigorate.royalsociety.org/ks4/chemical-photography-seeing-in-a-different-light/science-for-you-to-try.aspx) there are details as to how to reproduce William Herschel's original experiment using infrared radiation in sunlight.

A practical example to show that infrared radiation is refracted - changes its speed when going from one medium into another - is the use of infrared for transmitting information along optical fibres where the infrared pulses are travelling in an optically more dense medium and are totally internally reflected at the interface with an optically less dense medium.

Answer (score 3):

Electromagnetic waves refract when they crosses a boundary of two mediums where the mediums have differing indexes of refraction.

It's a pretty simple law:

$$n_1 \sin(\theta_1) = n_2 \sin(\theta_2).$$

This law applies to infrared just the same as visible light, the only difference between them is the frequency of the wave.

Comment: The IOR is, in general, dependent on the wavelength of the radiation $n(\lambda)$ and may thus be different for VIS and IR.

Comment: The statement about "this applies to..." is purely about the fact that snell's law describes the phenomena, but I can see how OP might conflate that with the indexes being the same. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

All electromagnetic radiations suffer the phenomenon of reflection,  refraction, diffraction, polarisation and interference.

Electromagnetic waves all the above phenomena (not only reflection or refraction, which can occur to longitudinal waves as well) mainly because they are transverse waves and have electric and magnetic fields vibrating perpendicular to each other.

Infrared radiations, a part of the spectrum beyond red and before micro waves, suffer all these phenomena.

Comment: All laws regarding these phenomena are also valid, like Snell's law in refraction.

Comment: There's nothing specific to transverse waves that makes them subject to refraction (and indeed to reflection, diffraction and interference). Longitudinal waves get refracted too.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty  Do longitudinal waves get polarised (I mentioned this too in the list of phenomena)?

Comment: That's a bit off topic, but do notice the conspicuous absence of polarization in my comment above. In any case, your answer implies that it's the transverse nature of EM waves that makes them refract, which is not the case.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Now see, I've edited it.

Comment: I don't think it's amazingly clear, but it's not incorrect or misleading now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56306/discussion-between-wrichik-basu-and-emilio-pisanty).