# Which material reflects and refracts infrared waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I want to know,which material partially refracts and partially reflects infrared waves.I couldn't find anything on google.Thank you

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322435/ A rock salt prism is often used to refrasct infra red.

Comment: does it also reflect?

Comment: I would imagine so. Here is some data about the refractive index of rock salt. https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ScientificPapers/nbsscientificpaper401vol16p701_A2b.pdf

Comment: does it reflect

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, for an electromagnetic radiation or simply light it can get refracted as well as reflected by any glass block or prism

for light to get reflected its incident angle should be greater than the critical angle of the block provided with it moving from denser to rarer medium that is from inside glass block to outside air so angle i > angle c it will undergo total internal reflection inside glass block.
This idea is used in optical fibres and also 'cat eyes'